# Reusing the TypePresenter in an ActivityDesigner

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, activitydesigner

The TypePresenter, which is the dropdown for selecting types when defining Variables and Arguments in the workflow designer, can be reused in your own ActivityDesigners.

It works great for the default types, but if you select **Browse for types...** the dialog which shows up is empty.  Instead of having a nice list of referenced assemblies, it just displays `<referenced assemblies>`.

I don't see anything in the API about how the dialog browses for types or what I might possibly need to do in order to "help" the browser figure out what assemblies to browse through.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, hello, me!  You must set the [TypePresenter.Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.view.typepresenter.context.aspx) (the ActivityDesigner's Context is fine) before the types will show up in the dialog.  That is where the type magic is (have to assume it is magic because what is actually there isn't fully documented).